# How to generate the weeks from current _date ( minus 12 months) and current _date (minus 7 days) in postgressql

Tags: sql, postgresql

The query should get data for example current_date(minus 12 months ) between current_date (minus 7 days(i.e . 1 week)) .

I should use like this 
select columns
from tablename
where current_date(minus 12 months ) between current_date (minus 7 days(i.e . 1 week))

In this format

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select week::date
  from generate_series(
  current_date - interval '12 month',
  current_date - interval '1 week',
  interval '1 week'
) q (week)
```

Here is a [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=105ee844298d6f842d4c0805427581f0) demo

Sample output:

```
    week
------------
 2016-05-24
 2016-05-31
 2016-06-07
 ...
 2016-06-28
 2016-07-05
 2016-07-12
 2017-05-02
 2017-05-09
 2017-05-16
(52 rows)
```

Comment: But i should use this in the where clause with a combination of between clause to filter the data .for example current_date(minus 12 months ) between current_date (minus 7 days(i.e . 1 week)) should be used using in where clause